# JMeter Is not saving the results to file when execute from Java Code

Tags: java, api, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

When I call jmeter test from gui then it works properly but when I call the ***run*** or ***runTests*** of Standard JMeter Engine, it do not save anything in */tmp/jmeter*.

How can I make it happen? How can I execute and fetch the api payload from Java Code saved from Save Response to File Listener.

I an using JMeter 5.0

```
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(getJmeterHome());
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterPropertiesFile.toString());
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    StandardJMeterEngine standardJMeterEngine = new StandardJMeterEngine();
    standardJMeterEngine.configure(rootTree);
    standardJMeterEngine.run();
```

**Builder Class**

```
public class MySaveResponseToFileBuilder {

private String name;
private String comment;
private boolean enabled;
private String fileName;
private String variableName;

public MySaveResponseToFileBuilder() {
    this.name = "Save Response to File";
    this.enabled = true;
    this.comment = "";
    this.fileName = "";
    this.variableName = "";
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public MySaveResponseToFileBuilder setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public MySaveResponseToFileBuilder setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
    return this;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public MySaveResponseToFileBuilder setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
    return this;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public MySaveResponseToFileBuilder setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    return this;
}

public String getVariableName() {
    return variableName;
}

public MySaveResponseToFileBuilder setVariableName(String variableName) {
    this.variableName = variableName;
    return this;
}

public ResultSaver build() {
    ResultSaver resultSaver = new ResultSaver();
    resultSaver.setName(this.getName());
    resultSaver.setComment(this.getComment());
    resultSaver.setEnabled(this.isEnabled());
    resultSaver.setVariableName(this.getVariableName());
    resultSaver.setFilename(this.getFileName());
    resultSaver.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ResultSaver.class.getName());
    resultSaver.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ResultSaverGui.class.getName());
    return resultSaver;
}
```

}

```
ResultSaver resultSaver = new MySaveResponseToFileBuilder().setName("Save Response to File").setFileName("/tmp/jmeter/${__samplerName()}").build();
```

Answer (score 2):

[Using JMeter listeners to store the test results is not the best idea](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) as:

- they don't add any value comparing to .jtl results files
- they are being fired after each sampler while .jtl results file subsystem stores the results in batches reducing disk IO negative concequences
- they consume CPU, RAM and disk resources due to their nature and above points

So instead of trying to add the listener consider using the following code before the `standardJMeterEngine.configure(rootTree);` line:

```
String jtlFile = "/path/to/results.jtl";
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename(jtlFile );
rootTree.add(rootTree.getArray()[0], logger);
```

It will add [Summariser](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/Summariser.html) and [ResultCollector](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/ResultCollector.html) to your [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Miscellaneous_Features) so when you run your code the results will be stored in  the .jtl results file which can be later on analyzed using [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) or you can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of it

Comment: This is the right answer especially when ramping up users